# Will you lose reputation when people downvote a question on Meta?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

If I ask a question on meta.stackoverflow.com and it is downvoted, will I lose reputation?

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^ No! (see my downvote?)

Comment: Your rep is safe even if you [can't be bothered to read the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Hmm.. not directly, but if you ask something that draws attention to any of your own main-site questions that can be perceived as bad, then... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The reputation on Meta is bound to your parent site's reputation.